# How to set up SQL User that can only do one thing (run stored procedure) and nothing else?

Tags: security, login, sql-server, ssms

I would like to allow any user within a certain group of our domain access to login to one of our databases and run a specific Stored Procedure. This is the only action these users should be able to perform. So far this is what I have implemented in testing:

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE LOGIN [Domain\Group] FROM WINDOWS;
GO





USE [TheDatabase];
GO

CREATE USER [Domain\Group] FROM LOGIN [Domain\Group];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName @TrueFalse VarChar(1), @Name VarChar(20)
    AS
    UPDATE [TheDatabase].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] SET REMOVED = @TrueFalse WHERE NAME = @Name
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::ProcedureName
    TO [Domain\Group]
GO
```

This allows me to connect to the SQL Server with a Windows account that belongs to the [Domain\Group] and run the Stored Procedure `EXEC ProcedureName 'T', 'NameOfRecord'`.

However I noticed that there's quite a bit of poking around that I'm able to do if I use SSMS to connect to the server with this account. I so far have not found anything that would allow the user to manipulate data, but there are a lot of things that the user can look at.

Preferably, I would essentially like the user to be able to run the SP, and only run the SP, nothing else, whether using SSMS or any other application.

Can I accomplish this or is viewing this information just an accepted risk of granting a user any level of access to a database?

### Info:

Through direct queries, I have been unable to do any action (that I know to test) with this user, but through a GUI like SSMS I can see certain information:

Within Object Explorer of SSMS pretty much all items can be expanded and viewed (Databases, System Databases, Security, Logins, Management, System Policies). I cannot be sure which of these specifically can be viewed in full as some of these items don't exist at all in the server, some of these items show a limited view (sa account sees more entries, but this user can see some), and some of these items show every entry to this user.

Through the GUI, the user can change properties of their own login such as the default database. This affects the entire [Domain\Group] login, not just the specific user that is logged in.

The following query returns one row, which shows the granted permission to execute on the specified Stored Procedure:

```
select 
    sys.schemas.name 'Schema', 
    sys.objects.name Object, 
    sys.database_principals.name username, 
    sys.database_permissions.type permissions_type, 
    sys.database_permissions.permission_name, 
    sys.database_permissions.state permission_state, 
    sys.database_permissions.state_desc, 
    state_desc + ' ' + permission_name + ' on ['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name + '] to [' + sys.database_principals.name + ']' COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS
from 
    sys.database_permissions
    join sys.objects on sys.database_permissions.major_id = sys.objects.object_id
    join sys.schemas on sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
    join sys.database_principals on sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id =  sys.database_principals.principal_id
```

GUI View of Users on database (viewed by sa account):
[image: GUI View of Users on database (viewed by sa account):]

Comment: What other permissions does the user in question have exactly?  Edit your question to include this vital information required in order to answer your question.

Comment: Please, verify that the user you're logging in is not a member of some other group with privileges on the databases or has privileges granted individually.

Comment: @Ramhound I will add a list with anything I witness. But I can't prove a negative and say that what I witness within my editor of choice (SSMS), is the only "ability" that this user will have without being explicitly granted. When I query the user's information the only granted permission is execute on the stored query. Through direct queries, the SP is the only thing this user can do. But through the GUI there are a lot of things the user can see. I can deny permissions one by one, but I need to know that any permissions that aren't explicitly granted are not applied to this user.